# How can you render the objects of a list that contains certain values?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I want to render only specific objects if it contains certain values. For instance, if we have these data:

```
{
  "product": [
     {
      "name": "laptop",
      "markets": [
         "Portugal",
         "France"
     ],
     "price": "1000"
},
{
     "name": "PS5",
      "markets": [
         "Portugal",
         "Spain"
     ],
     "price": "400"
}
]
}
```

So I only want to render the objects which values match market's values. For example if I'm in the "Spain" category I only want to render the second object, because the first doesn't contain Spain in markets. So far I've tried filtering but it returns undefined:

```
const filtered = product.markets.filter(word => word === currentMarket)
```

Comment: you can also use includes

```const filtered = product.markets.filter(word => currentMarket.includes(word))```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
const filtered = products.filter(product => product.markets.some(m => m === currentMarket));
```

This means "give me all products whose product's markets include currently market"